# How can I prevent Direct-X 12 from multi-adaptering?

Tags: directx-12

I asked this question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72539442/direct-x-12-is-using-the-wrong-and-multiple-adapters-in-c), but I want to ask something else on the topic. In Direct-X 12, does it default to multi-adapter and if so, where does it happen and how can I prevent it?

Comment: You are not even doing any multi-adaptering, it's not the default, nor can it happen implicitly with DX12, so you can't prevent it either.